# bpy: Updating After Switching Scenes

Tags: python, scripting, scene

there.

So, I know that you can switch scenes by setting the `bpy.context.screen.scene` reference to an existing scene reference, but doing so doesn't update `bpy.context.scene` immediately (at least, not within an add-on). I need this because I'm programmatically exporting data to FBX, and it relies on the scene reference in `bpy.context.scene`.

Is there some way to update Blender or the Window Manager or something, to make the context reference update after being set?

Comment: It seems to work just fine when I test it in a script. The active scene (`bpy.context.scene`) updates immediately after I change it via `bpy.context.screen.scene`. Maybe you're suffering from another problem?

Comment: I'm doing this from an add-on - it might be that add-ons behave differently from scripts?